# AWS Lambda Instances use Same or Different /temp Storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Parallel invocations of a lambda function results multiple lambda instances. Does this mean that each instance has its own ./temp storage? For example, if we have 10 instances of a lambda function, then AWS dedicates 10 * 512mb to the lambda function? Or just one unique ./temp storage will be shared among all instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different concurrent instances will have different `/tmp`. However, for consecutive invocations, lambda may reuse previous `/tmp` as part of [AWS Lambda execution environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html).

Comment: You are right about consecutive invocations.
But according to [https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/] : _'Each Lambda function receives 500MB'_.  So, It doesn't say 500mg for each instance, but it says 500mg for a lambda (including all of the instances of the lambda). Am I wrong?

Comment: @HoseinPanahi  `/tmp` can be re-used only if execution environment is re-used. Otherwise, each invocation has its own execution environment, which includes `/tmp`.

Comment: Okay, now the question is that each execution environment contains 500mg storage? Or 500mg is divided between all of them? 
In my example, if we have 10 execution environments then there is 10*512mg local storages totally?

Comment: @HoseinPanahi Yes, you will have 10 different `/tmp`. Its not one `/tmp` of size 10*512.

Comment: So, 10 different `/temp` and each `/temp` with 512mg.

Comment: @HoseinPanahi yes. If you require more storage then 512, you have to use S3 or EFS, which you can share between different functions and invocations.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks. That's truly great news.

Comment: This is a very useful information. Thanks @Marcin.

I read files from Lambda after processing is done then I shoot those to DB. However, I noted that some of the files had multiple copies in my DB. Luckily I was logging what I process, is when I saw that files from previous invocations were sent again. This was causing some duplicity in my DB.

Many thanks for this information.